# Is it possible to have multiple apps run out of one iOS .app file?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, project-structure

I have recently started work at a company where I am the sole developer taking over a very convoluted code base.  I am currently working on some iOS apps, but the only directory I have contains only one .xcodeproj file and only one .plist file.  To me this means that it is only one app.  However, there are other files in a controllers directory that contains controllers for the other apps, but they are still in the directory for the one app that corresponds to the .xcodeproj file and the .plist file.

To me it seems that there is only one app in this directory that contains code for the other apps.

My question is, is it possible to have sub apps that are all organized into one .app directory?  If so, how do I go about creating .plist files so they would launch?

Comment: I'm not certain enough to post it as an answer, but I'm pretty sure that you can't.

Comment: There's probably shared code and multiple targets with custom code, to decline one project into several different apps.

Comment: Why is there only one target and one plist then?  That is what I do not understand, there is no way to run the other apps since there are no other plists

Answer (score 7):

You can use a single project to share logic between multiple apps.

This concept in `iOS` is called [`XCode Target`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html).

For example if you had a application that needs to have multiple version, you will add a target for lite version and a second one for pro version.

Since they share common logic , you wouldn't want to duplicate projects. Instead you will add a target with appropriate plist for each.

Android has similar feature called flavors.

Comment: I have read about the different targets, but they would need different .plist files, correct?  Only one plist file exists

Comment: only one target and one plist that has the name for one app and nothing else.  Can I create a new target and have it point to the other apps?

Comment: yes when you add a new target it is a completely new app, you can even change the app names and icons

Comment: I understand that.  I just thought that there would already be another target since the app already exists.  I will look up how to create a new target from the existing code then I guess.  Thank you.  Since the other apps already exist should they not have a plist as well?

Comment: for each app you need to have the corresponding plist, xcode will do that for you

Comment: The first thing that I'd try to do is to use the *unmodified* code-base that you inherited, and try to re-generate all of apps:  this one, and all of the "other" ones. Verify that what you get *is,* in fact, the same things. Pore over anything and everything that the previous programmer may have left behind. (And if you can *give him/her a phone call,* that might save a lot of time if s/he is willing to answer. It's worth a try ...) Also be sure to drop a version-control tag at the starting-point you inherited, before you make *any* changes, so that you can reliably revert to it at any time.